# Why is Visual Studio 2015 not recognizing my Windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community edition and recently updated it with the windows SDK for creating universal windows application. However whenever I try to create an app, it doesn't load the xaml designer and it gives a notification

[image]

that I have to install windows 10 to use the xaml designer. But I have already installed windows 10, then why isn't visual studio not able to recognize it?

Comment: Are you sure your computer has the latest version of Windows 10 installed? Is it updated?

Comment: latest version? I had updated it in August, 2015 and it several updates have been installed automatically since then

Comment: it was last updated on 17th november 2015

Comment: Verify that all updates are installed. I installed it last month on one of my machines and last week it had a new version update to install. Look at the SDK that was installed and verify it's for your build number or lower.

Comment: if you currently use Win10 Version 1511 (run winver to see it), you have to install the VS2015 Update 1/Win10 1511 SDK

Comment: commonly due to sdk for the current W10 runtime not being installed!

You might be on W10 10240 but might have installed VS UWP Tools and SDK for W10 10586 (update 1 on W10 10240).

To fix ensure you have SDK for 10240 installed or simple upgrade your W10 to 10568.

Answer (score 2):

The target platform in your project is wrong.
Edit your project in text mode and find the

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Check if your TargetPlatformVersion and TargetPlatformMinVersion are 10.0.10240.0.

This is enought to load yours xamls.